# SSRS: Summing Lookupset not working

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm currently working on a report where I'm given 3 different datasets. The report essentially calculates the input, output and losses of a given food production process.

In dataset "Spices", contains the quantity of spices used under a field named "Qty_Spice". In dataset "Meat", contains the quantity of meat used under a field named "Qty_Meat". In dataset "Finished", contains the quantity of finished product used under a field "Qty_Finished".

I'm currently trying to create a table where the amount of input (spice+meat) is compared against output (finished product), such that the table looks like this:

Sum of Inputs (kg) | Finished Product (kg) | Losses (kg)

```
 10                   8                     2

 8                    5                      3
```

---

Total:

```
18                   13                      5
```

What I'm currently doing is using lookupset to get all inputs of both spices and meats (using lookupset instead of lookup because there are many different types of meats and spices used), then using a custom code named "Sumlookup" to sum the quantities lookupset returned.

The problem I'm having is that when I want to get the total sum of all inputs and all finished products (bottom of the table) using "Sumlookup" the table is only returning the first weight it finds. In the example above, it would return, 10, 8 and 2 as inputs, finished products and losses respectively.

Does anyone know how I should approach solving this?

Really appreciate any help

Here is the custom code I used for SumLookUp:

```
Public Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
Dim suma As Decimal = 0
For Each item As Decimal In items
suma += item
Next
Return suma
End Function
```

Comment: What expression are you using to call the function? My guess is your TOTAL line has some LOOKUPSET criteria that is used for the individual lines that isn't needed for the TOTAL and is filtering for the first one.

Comment: If possible I would merge the datasets with UNION ALL and avoid using lookup functions

Comment: I ended up asking someone with access to edit the query to merge the datasets. Thanks!